# contenteditable adding multiple spaces at the end on key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor, contenteditable

I have `contenteditable` `div` with following HTML in it

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor-note" id="FqzHgBZeHHT3QECD2">
  <span id="mSFK7wMphfKgBaCQg">Well</span>
  <span id="8jHKJyhFfqHw9WPpR">over</span>
  <span id="EGmCtEKaiPJkMKGSE">one</span>
  <span id="soDGqwvxvmzg9hF5W">,</span>
  <span id="uTEWcPrqoq9tZGYnK">my</span>
  <span id="8HQEjMNKLiv6XJkqp">guest</span>
  <span id="bYzzWYq5P4jTHLQ4S">today</span>
  <span id="uey8ghQ4yNN62aY8J">is</span>
</div>
```

When I want to enter extra text into it, when I enter any key it is adding lot of `&nbsp;` at the end of the div being made.

This gif shows what's happening: http://g.recordit.co/l8m6IQwmNb.gif

This is what happens when I entered one letter `n`

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor-note" id="FqzHgBZeHHT3QECD2">
  <span id="mSFK7wMphfKgBaCQg">Well</span>
  <span id="8jHKJyhFfqHw9WPpR">over</span>
  <span id="EGmCtEKaiPJkMKGSE">one</span>
  <span id="soDGqwvxvmzg9hF5W">,</span>
  <span id="uTEWcPrqoq9tZGYnK">my</span>
  <span id="8HQEjMNKLiv6XJkqp">guest</span>
  <span id="bYzzWYq5P4jTHLQ4S">today</span>
  <span id="uey8ghQ4yNN62aY8J">is</span>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;n
</div>
```

Here as you can see there is a lot of `&nbsp;` here, how can I solve this issue? I tried this in safari, same issue so this is not related to a browser at all.

Also, there are no event listeners attached to this div.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm using meteor js framework and this is the html code i'm using to generate this html

```
<div class="seg-editor">
  <div contenteditable="true" class="editor-note" id="{{segmentId}}">
    {{#each items}}
      <span id="{{_id}}">{{text}}</span>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

my `items` helper just returns values from db, there are no event listeners attached to this

Comment: Its working fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: where is your JS code? we can't judge what's causing this if you don't post it.

Comment: @chŝdk updated question, i'm using meteorjs framework to generate above html, i thought the issue is with plain html. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I change my meteor code to remove spaces in html like below in single line

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor-note" id="{{segmentId}}">{{#each items}}{{showSpace @index}}<span id="{{_id}}">{{text}}</span>{{/each}}</div>
```

instead of spreading in multiple line

```
<div class="seg-editor">
  <div contenteditable="true" class="editor-note" id="{{segmentId}}">
    {{#each items}}
      <span id="{{_id}}">{{text}}</span>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

that extra space issue was gone. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there will some `script` or `CSS` in your code which is the cause for this, So please check the cause or post a fiddle where this issue will reproduce.

**Note:** Checked your code on chrome and firefox, and it's working fine. You too can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7dz5pfk/1/).